# throw an exception on a method call

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, throws

How do I throw and UnsupportedOperationException on a method? So if I have an Iterable object and I'm trying to disallow the remove method for that object.

In the method below I'm returning an iterable object whose iterator's remove I need to disable by throwing an UnsupportedErrorException. Can I do this within the body of the method or how so?

```
  public Iterable<String> getInNodes (String destinationNodeName)  {
  if (!hasNode(destinationNodeName))
      return emptySetOfString;
  else {
  for(String e : nodeMap.get(destinationNodeName).inNodes)
  {
      emptySetOfString.add(e);
  }
  return emptySetOfString;
  }
}
```

Comment: `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
@Override
public void remove() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood your question.

If you have a normal Iterable, and you want to convert it to an Iterable that generates iterators on which `remove` can not be called, you can use this monstrosity made possible by anonymous subclassing:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = // normal Iterable<String> you already have...

Iterable<String> noRemoveIteratorGeneratingIterable = new Iterable<String>() {
    @Override        
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<String>() {
            Iterator<String> internalIterator = iterable.iterator();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return internalIterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public String next() {
                return internalIterator.next();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Nope!");
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class you can just @Override the original method

```
public class myIterable extends Iterable {
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then create Objects of this class instead of original Iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try throwing the message with appropriate message as well:

```
public void remove() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove is unsupported on this object");
}
```